# To call a command in the ghci automatically when it starts

Tags: haskell, ghci

Every time I run the `ghci` at first I call the `:set prompt "ghci> "` command manually. Can it happen automatically, instead of manually?

Comment: @Jefffrey Not exactly a dupe, but the question you link to is more general. Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Define `prompt` in one of the config files

Simply put that GHCi command in the appropriate GHCi config file (e.g. in your user-level GHCi config file `$HOME/.ghci` on Unix systems):

```
:set prompt "ghci> "
```

Create that file if it doesn't already exist. Then you won't have to run the command manually every time after starting GHCi. More detail about GHCi config files is available [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.4/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html).

By the way, another fashionable prompt is `λ>`.

### Don't forget to also customize `prompt-cont` (continuation prompt)

As pointed out by kqr [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564980/to-call-a-command-in-the-ghci-automatically-when-it-starts/27565123?noredirect=1#comment43558429_27565123), if you activate GHCi's multiline input mode (`:set +m`), you may also want to redefine, for consistency, `prompt-cont`—or `prompt2` prior to v8.2.1, as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564980/to-call-a-command-in-the-ghci-automatically-when-it-starts/27565123#comment79210327_27565123)—which corresponds to the continuation prompt. So your `.ghci` file should contain something like the following two lines:

```
:set prompt "λ> "
:set prompt-cont "λ| "
```

Otherwise, the default continuation prompt (`Prelude|`) will be used.

#### Test in GHCi

```hs
λ> :set +m
λ> let fact 0 = 1
λ|     fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
λ| 
(0.01 secs, 1547336 bytes)
λ> fact 5
120
```

Comment: Not that on some terminals an escape sequence like "\ESC[91mHELLO!\ESC[0m" will colour text quite nicely. Just something else you might like to add to your prompt!

Comment: @AJFarmar Colored prompts tend to distract me, but why not.

Comment: Recommended to also set `prompt2` (the continuation prompt that is used when you type multi-line definitions) so it doesn't switch back and forth between the default and your custom prompt. `prompt2` is available in GHC 7.8.1 at least, and not in my 7.6.3.

Comment: @kqr Very good point! Thanks.

Comment: not everyone use U*ix-like OSes, and there's not even a `~` character on the page you linked.

Comment: Since at least GHC version 8.2.1, `prompt2` has been replaced by `prompt-cont`.